# Neural Network Architecture Search

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization

I'm applying NN for regression purpose. The model has 30 Input nodes, 1 hidden layer and 1 output. In order to find the optimal architecture of the hidden layer, I've constructed a loop that:

- tests all possible hidden layer neurons (e.g. from 1 to 30)
- Calculates cross validation error for each loop iteration
- Filters the iteration that has the minimum error (e.g. 12 neurons)
- Applies the 12 neurons to the full data set

Can I consider this a form of regularization?
Reason for asking is because the package I deploy doesn't support L2 or dropout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing you need to set right is learning rate, which is very important. Usually, Adam or SGD optimzers should work. Also, you may need to make 3 partitions of data. Train data, on which you train the model. Validation data on which you try to fine tune the model, and finally the test data on which you finally evaluate the model.

If you don't have L2 or Dropout, you can consider "Early Stopping". Early stopping is also a method of regularization.

There are lots of concepts to understand. It's better you go through proper tutorials. Particularly, I find Lecture by Stanford on Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition very good. I assure you, once you go through all the tutorial, you'll be much better equipped. Here is the link  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT1JzLTH4G4&list=PL3FW7Lu3i5JvHM8ljYj-zLfQRF3EO8sYv

For neural network architecture search, there are three things you can consider - Random Search, Grid Search, and Bayesian Search or Model based search. I suggest you go for random search of hyperparameters.

All the best.

Comment: Thank you. I do apply early stopping indeed :)

Comment: This is not exhaustive, but will help you understand some very important basic concepts about deep learning. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKq-pmkekTk&list=PLlMkM4tgfjnJ3I-dbhO9JTw7gNty6o_2m  Enjoy!

Comment: Check out Bayesian Optimization, widely used for architecture search